# Serve joomla site on Amazon CDN

Tags: web-hosting, cdn

I want to set up the whole joomla site on CDN,
so that to increase the performance of our website.
How is it possible to put entire site on CDN?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to serve static (unchanging) assets like CSS and JavaScript from a CDN.

The dynamic pages (PHP) generated by a CMS are not good candidates for a CDN.

To setup a CDN, you'll host the website elsewhere (like you would normally).

Then, to fetch the assets, you'd create a pull zone that points to the folder where the assets live.

For example, if my site is `http://example.com` and my CSS/JS lives at `http://example.com/static`, I'd create a pull zone to grab the assets.

You can configure the CDN with a CNAME (subdomain) record so assets can be fetched from URLs like `http://cdn.example.com/somefile.css`.

You would then modify all references to static assets so that they're served by the CDN (using the `http://cdn...` URL.